Sort 1 column based on another column - Google Sheets
I’m building a jobs list spreadsheet in Google sheets. The 2 columns of note are status (new, assigned, in progress, completed, rejected) and priority (critical, high, normal, low)
So far I have a script where it will automatically sort by 1 of the columns. However, I would like it to sort by status and within each status for it to sort by priority.
So the finish result should be all the new jobs at the top of the list, sorted by priority from critical down to low and then all the assigned jobs sorted by priority etc.
I’m unsure how to go about changing the sort method to do this.
I have tried looking around and it will probably need nested for or nested for each loops but I’m unsure of the correct code.

It is always recommended to demonstrate what you did within your question by including your: codes, formulas, sharing a sample sheet, etc. This will help people reading your question to give you a quicker response.

I would need to see a your data but I would attempt to use the custom sort feature of arrays.

Try using the array filter and map methods

Sort both columns using range.sort:
range.sort([2,1])

For this to work, the  priority parameters should have an inherent order. For example, Instead of text data, numeric data like 1 for CRITICAL, 2 for HIGH, etc provides order.

That’s brilliant, thank you. I’m guessing the above code would sort column 2 and then would sort column 1?

@PaulAspinall Yes. Click the link to know more.
